# Need a little help to fix issues to install Magento

Tags: php, magento, configuration, installation

I'm trying so hard to install Magento, i've made many researches, it is not user friendly at all seems like.

I have these issues :

Your PHP Version is 5.6.15, but always_populate_raw_post_data = 0. $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated from PHP 5.6 on wards and will be removed in PHP 7.0. This will stop the installer from running. Please open your php.ini file and set always_populate_raw_post_data to -1. If you need more help please call your hosting provider.

(I've opened php.ini on XAMPP, i've changed it like this :
; Always populate the $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA variable. PHP's default behavior is
; to disable this feature.
; http://php.net/always-populate-raw-post-data
always_populate_raw_post_data = -1

1 missing PHP extensions
PHP Extension intl

I have the folder in Xampp/Xamppfiles 
When i've tried yum install intl, also intl-3.0.0 
Doesn't work

Last issues which are ridiculous : 
4 file permission not met.

The fourth say this : 
writable directory permission.

I did it manually on all folders, read and write rights, so it should work.

Thanks for help!!

Comment: Your magento version

Answer (score 0):

Go to

```
{magento_root}/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/PhpReadinessCheck.php
```

And find this line and add  `return []; //`

```
private function checkPopulateRawPostSetting(){
    // HHVM and PHP 7does not support 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to be set to -1
    if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '7.0.0-beta') >= 0 || defined('HHVM_VERSION')) {
        return [];
}

return []; //       <-- ADD THIS LINE
[...]
```

Run again the Readiness Check: T he PHP Settings Check gets a green light.